# Reading hyperlink information from an excel file using .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, excel, hyperlink

I am reading an excel file in C#.NET. The data is being read successfully but there is problem with some hyperlinks stored in the excel file.

I can read their text but i dont know how to get the underlying link/url of the column.

I couldnt find much help on google as well. if someone has worked in a similar situation please let me know what can be done.

edit::: i am using OleDb namespace for establishing a connection with the Excel file so if someone can post a solution which applies to this situation please do.

Comment: How are you reading in the file? This will be important for helping find and fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can try some thing like this using Excel Interop

```
for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count; ++j)
    {
        Range rng = (Range)sheet.UsedRange[i, j];
        if (rng != null)
        {
            if(rng.Hyperlinks.Count > 0)
            {
                string url = rng.Hyperlinks[1].Address; // always throw an exception.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I dont think you can retrieve hyperlinks using Oledb. you could try reading the file into a text stream and look for link patterns in the stream.

Comment: i m using oledbconnection so i think this is not applicable :(

Comment: Using Excel interop on a web server is not a good idea - see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Comment: usin excels is itself not a good idea in a web app :), but when you are forced to use it interop is as good as anything else